# How to display multiple data in a single row data cell in HTML?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to display a Table as shown below.

[image]

However, what I got is:

[image]

How to show multiple data in a single row data cell in HTML?
Can it be done in HTML itself?

Thank you

My code:

```
<h1>Color of Fruits</h1>

<table class = "GFtable"> 
<tr>
      <th>Color of Fruits</th>  <th>Types of Fruits</th>
 </tr>

 <tr *ngFor="let greenfruits of farmFruits; let a = index">
      <div style="padding-top: 5px; width: 100%">
           <td>{{ greenColor }} [{{ farmFruitsNum[a].length }}]</td>
      </div> 

      <td>
           <div
            *ngFor="let fruits of farmFruitsNum[a]; let b = index">
             {{ fruits }}
           <div class="asteriskSymbol"
            [ngStyle]="{
             display:b == farmFruitsNum[a].length - 1 ? 'none' : 'block'}">
            *
            </div>
            </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try make it into `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.

Try this:

```
<h1>Color of Fruits</h1><table> 
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Color of Fruits</th>  <th>Types of Fruits</th>
    </tr> 
</thead></table>


<div *ngFor="let greenfruits of farmFruits; let a = index">
     <div style="padding-top: 5px; width: 100%">
         <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>
                {{ greenColor }} [{{ farmFruitsNum[a].length }}]
            </td>
            <td>
                <div
                *ngFor="let fruits of farmFruitsNum[a]; let b = index">
                {{ fruits }}
                <div class="asteriskSymbol"
                [ngStyle]="{
                display:b == farmFruitsNum[a].length - 1 ? 'none' : 'block'}">
                *
                </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
</div>
```